# Jest spying on function called from within another

Tags: jestjs

I have the following two files:

functions.js

```
function getOne() {
  return 1;
}

function getTen() {
  let val = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    val+= getOne();
  }
  return val;
}

module.exports = {
                  getOne,
                  getTen,
                 }
```

functions.test.js

```
const numberFunctions = require('../functions.js');
const getOne = numberFunctions.getOne;
const getTen = numberFunctions.getTen;

// passes
test('I should be able to get the number 1', () => {
  expect(getOne()).toBe(1);
});

describe('The getTen function', () => {
  // passes
  it('should return 10', () => {
    expect(getTen()).toBe(10);
  });

  // fails
  it('should call the getOne method 10 times', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(numberFunctions, 'getOne');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
  });
});
```

I'm trying to ensure that the the function getOne has been called from within the getTen function. In total it should be called 10 times, but my spy always claims that it has been called **zero** times.

I've tried rearranging my test so that I mock the getOne function as a global e.g.

```
it('should call the getOne method 10 times', () => {
    global.getOne = jest.fn(() => 1);
    expect(global.getOne).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
  });
```

But this results in the same outcome. How can I spy on the getOne function being called from within the getTen function?

Comment: To pre-empt the comments: I know that, if this were a real example, it would be sufficient to test the output of `getTen` rather than to try and interrogate what it's doing internally. I'm interested in seeing if the method described above would be possible if, say, the purpose of `getTen` was to simply call `getOne` multiple times without returning anything itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get this working by changing the `getOne` function called by `getTen` to directly reference the one exported by the function. Otherwise it seems to be referencing some internally scoped function which is *not* the one that is exported, making it impossible to spy on.

This is explained in more detail in [this github conversation](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/936), but to get my test to work as expected meant that I had to refactor my code to be:

```
function getOne() {
  return 1;
}

function getTen() {
  let val = 0;
  for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    val+= module.exports.getOne(); // <-- this line changed
  }
  return val;
}

module.exports = {
                  getOne,
                  getTen,
                 }
```

Now, rather than being internally scoped, the inner function refers to the exported one and can be spied on.